# Best Electric Vehicle Motor for DIY

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor

Which motor would be Cheap and a motor which can generate as well as produce also...
I am looking for a prototype for a car so it needs to cost less

Comment: This question is very bad written. You should rewrite it.

Comment: Series-connected brushed DC motor. It has a torque-speed characteristic best suited for vehicles and only needs a DC source. Putting it into generative mode only requires one double-pole double-throw switch.

Comment: what is `official car`?

Answer (score 2):

Cheap usually has poor quality. 
If you must buy a cheap motor because you do not have enough money to buy a good motor then you do not need a motor. Take a bus instead.

I would use a DC brushless motor because it does not have brushes that wear out and has a wide RPM range without losing much torque. With the wide RPM range then the car might not need a transmission for various speeds.